# How can i get the package name of the class inside the .jar File

Tags: java, rest, jar, package, optaplanner

I have 2 project. First is a restful webservice the other is a java project(optaplanner). I want to run optaplanner with my webservice so I made it a `.jar` file. When I start the project it returns `"cannot load java class"` exception. 
I think about it and I find a theory. I think while the `SolverConfig.xml` is reading by `XStream`, `XStream` try to convert it to an `SolverConfig class` type and it couldn't find `"org.optaplanner.examples.project.domain.(class)"` inside the webservice project when try to add solutionclass and entityclass variables from the classes, because this path is inside the jar file. The question is how I can define these classes or drools file from jar file inside the `Solverconfig.xml`.

Comment: Hi, What class it failed to load? Provide the class name.

Comment: SolutionClass and entityClass. The exception isn't because of an specific class. This is about the structure. Because i try to run it as a desktop project and it works but when i generate it to jar file it couldn't reach to jar file's projects it search the class inside the webservice project.

Comment: Did you add the jar file in class path? I seems like class path issue.

Comment: i used jar file as a library and i add it to artifacts. and deploy it as a war file to glassfish server. is there a missing step ?

Comment: Clearly java virtual machine unable to find the files it mentioned in your error message.

Comment: I know because they are inside the .jar File. And the started project is a restful webservice. I don't know how can i say to solverconfig.xml "look at the jar file for these classes."

Comment: Is your jar file  just a library file? If so put them inside lib. For this just create a `lib` folder inside WEB-INF and add all the dependent jar files in it.

Comment: already i did it. The problem is when XStream read the solver config and it try to find a class inside org.optaplanner.examples.project.XXX.java. inside src file. It couldn't find it because the runnig project is a restful webservice and the org.optaplanner.examples.project.XXX.java file is inside the .jar File